# tbb::cache_aligned_allocator: Getting "request for member...which is of non-class type" with __m128i. User error or bug?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, sse, tbb

I'm trying to use __m128i as the value type of a cache-aligned vector with GCC, and I'm getting the following error:

> /usr/include/tbb/cache_aligned_allocator.h:105:32: error: request for member ‘~tbb::cache_aligned_allocator<__vector(2) long long int>::value_type’ in ‘* p’, which is of non-class type ‘tbb::cache_aligned_allocator<__vector(2) long long int>::value_type {aka __vector(2) long long int}’

The compiler traces it to the following line in tbb/cache_aligned_allocator.h:

```
void destroy( pointer p ) {p->~value_type();}
```

Here is the code that triggers the compiler error:

```
#include <vector>
#include <emmintrin.h>
#include <tbb/cache_aligned_allocator.h>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int, tbb::cache_aligned_allocator<int> > success;
    std::vector<__m128i, tbb::cache_aligned_allocator<__m128i> > failure;
    return 0;
}
```

According to Debian versioning, my GCC version is 4.6.1-2, and my TBB version is 3.0+r147-1.
Is this a bug in Threading Building Blocks, or am I misusing something?

Comment: Please bear with me...I'm trying to edit to get the proper formatting.

Comment: Thanks!  I ended up making the same edits as you at the same time, too. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem lies with how the `__m128` types are implemented in gcc. They are not actual types in the C++ sense, in that they are neither POD (Plain Old Data, like int/double/char/etc.) nor classes. The `vector(2) long long int` identifier is how gcc refers to the type internally. The error that you showed is from the compiler complaining about not being able to find a destructor for `__m128i` because it is not a class type.

A workaround for this could involve creating your own type that is 128 bits in size and using a vector of those instead. You could provide a custom cast operator to the `__m128i` type for convenience if you want, or just cast a pointer to the first element in the vector to a `__m128i` if you just want to use the vector as a convenient memory allocation mechanism.

Comment: Thanks.  I really do just want to use the vector as a convenient memory allocation mechanism (since my arrays are too big to fit on the stack, and non-RAII dynamic arrays will leak with exceptions).  My current workaround is creating a vector of 32-bit ints, giving it four times as many elements, and casting the pointer to the internal array to __m128i.  However, creating a 128-bit type would be a bit cleaner.  (EDIT:  Removed stupid question, haha.)